# User can upload files, but can't link to them

Tags: users, files

I have an author user who is able to upload files Using the Attachment field, however when trying to link to the same file via the Link icon in the text editor, they can't see the file they've just uploaded.

It seems to be a permissions issue... But I can't exactly figure out how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The upload destination for the attachment field is set to Public

As a test run, I uploaded two different files, one as user1 and another as a different user. Running the ls-l command, they both get uploaded the same, with same permissions and user...

The files get uploaded to /public_html/sites/default/files

**I am able to browse to the file the other user creates by using user1 account. But this is not the solution, as I want the authors to be able to link to their own files they upload...**

Comment: Are you using Media module?

Comment: I am using IMCE + WYSIWYG @heshanlk

Comment: The nodes that these files are attached to, are they published?

Comment: Yes, the node is published, I am able to link to the file attached by user7 when logged in as user1, but user7 is unable to link to the file they uploaded :( @longboardnode

Comment: Did you check the IMCE profile for user7 to make sure they have browse permissions? admin/config/media/imce

Comment: Thanks again @longboardnode
In the Sample profile.................

Display file browser tab in user profile pages.  is Ticked................

Under Directories....

<root> u%uid Browse, Upload and thumbnails are all ticked.....

In /admin/config/media/imce .... user-1 is using User-1 profile, authenticated user is set to use Sample profile. The private files for authenticated user is set to None....

Comment: what is <root>u%uid - shouldn't it point to your public:// directory, ie <root>/sites/default/files?

Comment: Is it public or private filesystem?

Comment: Thank you @longboardnode ....

I changed the Sample profile so the Directory path is now set to <root>/sites/default/files for browse upload and thumbnails, and the Including subdirectories is ticked.


The file gets uploaded to /public_html/sites/default/files .... (I can see it using ssh/putty that it has been uploaded)............When I try to link using a Link icon, the file browser defaults to <root>/sites/default/files but the folder seems to be empty.... 

When browsing as a user1, the file browser defaults to <root> and the files uploaded are listed there (????)

Comment: It's public @Mołot

Comment: If I set the Directory path for Sample profile to <root>/. (so it matches the user-1 profile), then the author user is able to view the files uploaded to /public_html/sites/default/files. Is this a good idea from a security perspective? @longboardnode

Comment: If I set the Directory path for Sample profile to <root>/. (so it matches the user-1 profile), then the author user is able to view the files uploaded to /public_html/sites/default/files. Is this a good idea from a security perspective? @Mołot

Comment: @kine456 I responded below in an answer, hopefully the settings there resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's a good idea security wise as it allows your "Samplers" access to your root and that could wreak havoc on your system.

In IMCEs config page "admin/config/media/imce/profile/edit/[Sample's uid]" right under Profile Name, make sure you tick the "Display file browser tab in user profile pages." checkbox, and uncheck the "include subdirectories" checkbox under the  directory for Sample. Then clear all your caches (including browser) and it should work hopefully :-)